# How do I add a number to an NSURL? Too many arguments error

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurl

I've got a small problem that seems a little bit odd to me. I often used NSString or NSLog while adding NSNumbers into several places:

```
NSNumber *categoryId = [[NSNumber alloc]initWithInt:0];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://shop.rs/api/json.php?action=getCategoryByCategory&category=%i",[categoryId integerValue]];
```

Now xcode tells me that I'm too many arguments. What am I doing wrong? Setting up an NSNumber into NSStrings or NSLogs works as I did it above.

Best Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is wrong is on

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://shop.rs/api/json.php?action=getCategoryByCategory&category=%i",[categoryId integerValue]];
```

you are calling `URLWithString:` and then pass in a string that is not being formatted correctly. If you want to do it all on one line then you need to be using `stringWithFormat:` like

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://shop.rs/api/json.php?action=getCategoryByCategory&category=%i",[categoryId integerValue]]];
```

Because it is adding a parameter you can't just create a string like you normally would with `@"some text"` you need to format it using the `stringWithFormat:` which will return an `NSString *` with the text held within `@""` and the paramters you pass in. So `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"My String will come with %@", @"Apples"];` this would provide an `NSString` with `"My String will come with Apples"`. For more information check out the [Apple Documentation for `NSString` and `stringWithFormat:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html)

Comment: @Downvoter please state reason for downvote as this is correct.

Comment: @r3n no problem the important thing is that it works for you.

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://shop.rs/api/json.phpaction=getCategoryByCategory&category=%i", [categoryId integerValue]]];
```

*Initially code was wrong because of : "categoryId integerValue]" (I forgot a '[').*

Comment: Not sure where my initial comment has gone but this was initially completely wrong. However whilst the code has been correct there is no description of what was initially wrong and why do it this way. Note I edited so I could remove my -1 will provide +1 if you provide more detail

Comment: Initially code was wrong because of : [categoryId integerValue], you haven't try to understanding the code... Bad way for a developper ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NSString` to form your `NSURL`. You can then pass it to your `URLWithString` like below:

```
NSNumber *categoryId = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:0]; 
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://shop.rs/api/json.php?action=getCategoryByCategory&category=%i",[categoryId integerValue]];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
```

Comment: there is no need to alloc categoryId here. 

NSNumber *categoryId = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:0];